# Photoshop CS4 color profile weirdness

Tags: windows-7, adobe-photoshop, colors, color-profiles

My color profile in Photoshop CS4 on Windows is always set to "Monitor RGB" when I startup photoshop, which gives me a weird color tone as shown in the screenshot below.

For example, this is how calculator looks like in Photoshop.

I can then go to View > Proof setup > Windows RGB to fix it. However every time I start Photoshop it is again wrong and I have to make this setting over and over again. How can I fix this forever?

[image]

Comment: I feel your pain.

Comment: What happened to your screen shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1:

Choose a collection of default settings that best reflect your workflow

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Photoshop/11.0/WS921B081D-C675-40ff-93AD-6A60C641A136.html